# Access pytest session or arguments in pytest_runtest_logreport

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am trying to build a pytest plugin that utilizes the `pytest_runtest_logreport` in order to invoke some code everytime a test fails. I'd like to gate this plugin with a CLI argument I have added using the `pytest_addoption` hook. Unfortunately I can't seem to figure out how to access the pytest session state or arguments inside the `pytest_runtest_logreport` hook. Is there a way to do this? I don't see it in the hookspec.

Answer (score 5):

You can't get the session from the standard `TestReport` object. However, you can introduce a custom wrapper around the [`pytest_runtest_makereport`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_runtest_makereport) hook (the one that creates the report object), where you can attach the session yourself. Example:

```
import pytest


@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    out = yield
    report = out.get_result()
    report.session = item.session


def pytest_runtest_logreport(report):
    print(report.session)
```

Another example of passing state between hooks is a plugin class. Example with accessing `config` object in `pytest_runtest_logreport`:

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.tryfirst
def pytest_configure(config):
    p = MyPlugin(config)
    config.pluginmanager.register(p, 'my_plugin')


class MyPlugin:
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config

    def pytest_runtest_logreport(self, report):
        print(report, self.config)
```

Comment: You rock. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @hoefling, very nice. Works great for me... until I try using pytest-xdist, where it complains about the session item not being serializable. I really only need the config (i.e., session.config), but even that isn't serializable. Any ideas for a clever trick?

Comment: @Mikeage I have updated the answer with an example. However, `xdist` is tricky in general; this example works b/c both hooks run in master process. If you need to pass data between workers, use workerinputs where you can put anything that is pickleable.

Comment: Thanks. I used to use pytest.config, but that's now deprecated. If I pass the dict within session.config, it works, but doesn't propagate back from the workers to the master (pytest.config does). I might need to play around with that one a bit more (my use case is collecting test results along with a ton of private data and then processing it all in a session finish hook on the master)

Comment: Looks like the plugin method also works for xdist. Thank you!