# Identifying Pytest execution phase "sections" using hooks

Tags: plugins, pytest

I am writing a Pytest plugin, and I would like to mark the beginning and end of some sections (phases of execution) in the console output. I've got all of the sections I am interested in identified, except for the section that has:

```
======== FAILURES ========
_________ test_1 _________
_________ test_2 _________
_________ test_3 _________
etc...
```

(whatever that section is called). What hook am I missing that would allow me to mark this?

My plugin.py looks like:

```
MARKERS = {
    "pytest_session_start_1": "==>SESSION_START_MARKER_1<==",
    "pytest_session_start_2": "==>SESSION_START_MARKER_2<==",
    "pytest_session_finish_1": "==>SESSION_FINISH_MARKER_1<==",
    "pytest_session_finish_2": "==>SESSION_FINISH_MARKER_2<==",
    "pytest_failure_1": "==>FAILURE_MARKER_1<==",
    "pytest_failure_2": "==>FAILURE_MARKER_2<==",
}

@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    """
    Write section-begin marker before session starts
    """
    print(MARKERS["pytest_session_start_1"])
    out = yield
    print(MARKERS["pytest_session_start_2"])

@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_sessionfinish(session):
    """
    Write section-end marker after session finishes
    """
    print(MARKERS["pytest_session_finish_1"])
    yield
    print(MARKERS["pytest_session_finish_2"])

@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    """
    Attach session info to report for later use in pytest_runtest_logreport
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54717786/access-pytest-session-or-arguments-in-pytest-runtest-logreport
    """
    out = yield
    report = out.get_result()
    report.session = item.session

@pytest.hookimpl(trylast=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_logreport(report):  # sourcery skip: merge-nested-ifs
    """
    Write pytest markers around all failed testcases
    """
    yield
    if report.failed and report.when == "call":
        report.longrepr.chain[0][0].reprentries[0].lines.insert(
            0, MARKERS["pytest_failure_1"]
        )
        report.longrepr.chain[0][0].extraline = MARKERS["pytest_failure_2"]
```

It gives me the following output:

```
==>SESSION_START_MARKER_1<==
=================================== test session starts ====================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.5, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /Users/Jeff

==>SESSION_START_MARKER_2<==
collected 4 items                                                                          

tests/tests.py FF.F                                                       [100%]==>SESSION_FINISH_MARKER_1<==
==>SESSION_FINISH_MARKER_2<==


========================================= FAILURES =========================================
_______________________________________ test_version _______________________________________

==>FAILURE_MARKER_1<==
    def test_version():
>       assert __version__ == "0.1.0"
E       AssertionError: assert '0.5.0' == '0.1.0'
E         - 0.1.0
E         ?   ^
E         + 0.5.0
E         ?   ^

tests/test_pytest.py:14: AssertionError
==>FAILURE_MARKER_2<==
____________________________________ test_which_fails_1 ____________________________________

==>FAILURE_MARKER_1<==
    def test_which_fails_1():
>       assert 0
E       assert 0

tests/test_pytest.py:18: AssertionError
==>FAILURE_MARKER_2<==
____________________________________ test_which_fails_2 ____________________________________

==>FAILURE_MARKER_1<==
    def test_which_fails_2():
>       assert 0
E       assert 0

tests/test_pytest.py:26: AssertionError
==>FAILURE_MARKER_2<==
================================= short test summary info ==================================
FAILED tests/test_pytest.py::test_version - AssertionError: assert '0.5.0' == '0.1.0'
FAILED tests/test_pytest.py::test_which_fails_1 - assert 0
FAILED tests/test_pytest.py::test_which_fails_2 - assert 0
=============================== 3 failed, 1 passed in 10.76s ===============================
```

The only thing I am missing is some marks around the section:

```
========================================= FAILURES =========================================
_______________________________________ test_version _______________________________________
```

I appreciate any help you could give!

Comment: So instead of test_version you want to have it printed as test_1?

Comment: No, I want to be able to print "==>SECTION_MARKER_1<==" before the "======FAILURES======" and "_____test_version_____" lines. Then I want to to print "==>SECTION_MARKER_2<==" right after that. Basically, I am trying to mark all the different sections of the output so I can do some manipulation of those sections later.